# How to launch DialogFragment with data from listview row

Tags: java, android, listview, fragment

I have an activity with a listview in it. I setOnItemLongClickListener which will launch a DialogFragment (that has an EditTexts inside) but I want this fragment to be show with data from the row which it was launched from.

This is what I have so far but it is not working:

```
personalzone_lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            TrempData row_data = adapter.getItem(position);

            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            Addtremp trempDialog = new Addtremp();

            trempDialog.name.setText(row_data.get_name().toString());
            trempDialog.phone.setText(row_data.get_phone().toString());
            trempDialog.from.setText(row_data.get_from().toString());
            trempDialog.to.setText(row_data.get_to().toString());
            trempDialog.date.setText(row_data.get_date().toString());
            trempDialog.time.setText(row_data.get_time().toString());
            trempDialog.extra.setText(row_data.get_extras().toString());

            trempDialog.show(manager, "Addtremp");
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Comment: what is the problem? I explained the problem and gave a code snippet... I searched for an answer but no one worked